# Hide GPS icon while GPS is on in android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to hide GPS icon permanently for my application so that user is unknown that GPS is enabled. I want to know if we can do it by using JNi or any other way in android?

Comment: Hopefully not, for obvious privacy reasons. Note that this also is illegal in some jurisdictions, as I understand it.

Comment: What reason do you have for trying to deceive your users? This sounds objectionable!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't.

This seems to be a system-controlled function - so, you have to write your own ROM to achieve this goal.